# How to check if an email address in valid in PHP?

Tags: php

I need a php program to check mail id

```
$txt="swatimishra298@gmail.com";
```

and I need to find whether its a valid mail id or not. `@` should not be repeated and only `A-za-z _ . @` are allowed

My program:

```
 <?php

 echo "Hello world!<br>";
 $txt="swatimishra298gmail.com";
 $i = strlen("swatimishra298gmail.com");

 for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {

 $name=substr( $txt ,0, $j);

 do
 {
   $j++;
 }while( $j == '@' );
   echo "Its a mail id!"; 
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: you are asking two things: **(1)** if a mail is valid **(2)** *`@` should not be repeated and only `A-za-z _ . @` are allowed* The (1) is not compatible with (2).(2) is a subset of (1). Please clarify what do you want. If you want (1) you are looking for a full email validator, something not so simple. If you want (2) a simple regex will do.

Answer (score 3):

Use `filter_var`. Try with -

```
filter_var($txt, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

It will return `false` if fails.